# Pipe pyinstaller output possible?

Tags: linux, time

I am trying to build a binary of a python application with pyinstaller.
My aim is it to get the build time, so I tried the following options

- `time pyinstaller --bootloader-ignore-signals --onefile <file> | tee pyinstaller.log`
- `time pyinstaller --bootloader-ignore-signals --onefile <file> >> pyinstaller.log`

Nothing of these worked. Any ideas how to realise my idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you all need is the output of pyinstaller and it's execution time:

```
(time pyinstaller --bootloader-ignore-signals --onefile script.py) |& tee pyinstaller.log
```

or if you only need the result of the execution time, use some grouping to redirect the output of `time`:

```
{ time pyinstaller --bootloader-ignore-signals --onefile script.py 2>&3; } 3>&2 2>pyinstaller.log
```